# Normalising images before learning in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, image, machine-learning, normalization, pytorch

I want to apply a transform to standardise the images in my dataset before learning in pytorch. I hear this improves learning dramatically. I think Pytorch by default divides all image pixel values by 255 before puttint them in tensors, does this pose a problem for standardization?. The online guide recommends we proceed in the following way.

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

However, how the 0.5 here is just an example I found, it is not the mean or variance for the channels of my data.

So my question is how is the mean and standard deviation derived? Do we need to flatten and append all the green pixel values of the input pictures then calculate the mean and standard deviation? Then repeat for all the other colours. is that how it's done?

I heard there was another approach that tries to calculate an "average picture" to standardise with. What is the difference in result?

Answer (score 0):

Run this code to get the values of mean, standard deviation, standard deviation with delta degrees of freedom = 1.

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(*torch_dataset*, batch_size=4096, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)

data_mean = [] # Mean of the dataset
data_std0 = [] # std of dataset
data_std1 = [] # std with ddof = 1
for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
    # shape (batch_size, 3, height, width)
    numpy_image = data['image'].numpy()

    # shape (3,)
    batch_mean = np.mean(numpy_image, axis=(0,2,3))
    batch_std0 = np.std(numpy_image, axis=(0,2,3))
    batch_std1 = np.std(numpy_image, axis=(0,2,3), ddof=1)

    data_mean.append(batch_mean)
    data_std0.append(batch_std0)
    data_std1.append(batch_std1)

# shape (num_iterations, 3) -> (mean across 0th axis) -> shape (3,)
data_mean = np.array(data_mean).mean(axis=0)
data_std0 = np.array(data_std0).mean(axis=0)
data_std1 = np.array(data_std1).mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: why did you choose batch_size=4096? Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: code was copy-pasted from here, justification therein https://forums.fast.ai/t/image-normalization-in-pytorch/7534/7